# flyway created tables without any columns

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, maven, flyway

I have a few migrations scripts that are pretty basic. e.g,:

```
create table PERSON (
    ID int not null,
    NAME varchar(100) not null
);
```

I also have the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.adamg</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flyway-test</name>
    <description>flyway-test</description>
    <properties>
        <flyway-maven-plugin.version>10.7.1</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
        <flyway.version>4.0.3</flyway.version>
        <database.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reputations</database.url>
        <database.user>postgres</database.user>
        <database.password>1234</database.password>
        <postgres.driver.version>9.2-1002.jdbc4</postgres.driver.version>
        <jooq.version>3.16.12</jooq.version>
        <flyway.cleanDisabled>false</flyway.cleanDisabled>

        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version> <!-- Use the correct version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.10.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flyway-clean</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flyway-migrate</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${database.url}</url>
                    <user>${database.user}</user>
                    <password>${database.password}</password>
<!--                    <url>jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobardb</url>-->
<!--                    <user>sa</user>-->
                    <locations>
                        <location>classpath:db/migration</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>LATEST</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-jooq</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4.1212</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>${database.url}</url>
                        <user>${database.user}</user>
                        <password>${database.password}</password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>org.jooq.codegen.maven.example</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am running postgres using docker, and I created a db in postgres called "reputations", and ran `mvn flyway:migrate`. It seemed to work - that is, I see that tables were created under the "public" schema for my database.

But when I try to inspect the tables in pgAdmin, I see they have no columns. If I click on "view rows" for a given table, I just get "The specified object could not be found.".

[image]

Further, when I inspect what flyway did by running `mvn flyway:info`, I see the following:

[image]

1. Why are my tables empty?
2. Why did it ignore the last migration
3. Why are the migrations out of order?